# use opaque div for ie6 only

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

I have a white/transparent logo in a transparent div which is on top of a picture.  Problem is that with ie6, the transparent part of the logo becomes white and it just appears as a white square.  Is there anyway to turn the div into black background when ie is being used?  I'm using mootools for JavaScript btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an IE hack:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
   <style type='text/css'>

         .some_div {
              background: black;
          }    

   </style>
<![endif]-->
```

This will affect all IE's less than IE 7

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use conditional style sheet for ie6 only like this :

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="YourStyle.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<![endif]-->
```

then the yorstyle.css file will contain css style for ie6 only

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible [css solution](http://www.unintentionallyblank.co.uk/2007/05/07/cross-browser-background-transparency-with-css/):

```
div {

background:transparent url(transparent.png);

}

<!--[If IE 6]>

<style type=”text/css”>

#transparent {

background:#fff none;

filter:alpha(opacity=50);

height:1%;

}

#transparent * {

    filter:alpha(opacity=100);

    position:relative;

}

</style>

<![endif]-->
```

The other solution would be to stop supporting IE6 (my preference) ;)

Comment: agreed -- best option is just not to bother supporting IE6. It's only used by about 1.5% these days anyway, and falling. We stopped supporting it over a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

from boilerplate:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="no-js ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="no-js ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="no-js ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

which affords in the SAME stylesheet to have even browser-specific rules w/o referencing multiple files, inline code and style tags which affect performance.

```
div.transparent {
    opacity: .6;
}

.ie6 div.transparent {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    background: black;
}
```

your problem sounds like it could be a png alpha issue as well though, depends.

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/ is a pretty good fix, if you don't have element storage or events bound to the element.